# Image/CSS in Mailer in Rails is not applied only in Gmail

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am making a Rails app. When user signs up, I send a confirmation mailer using devise.

I found out that my image and css is loaded in other email provider like hotmail. However, image/css in my mailer view is not loaded properly in gmail. I wonder why it only does not work in gmail. I put all CSS in inline style since I saw that I cannot add CSS files to mailer views.

In `production.rb`, I set asset_host:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host =  ENV['DEFAULT_HOST']
```

Below is mailer code I have in Rails:

```
<body style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
<div class="main wrapper clearfix">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        padding: 20px 50px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        background-color: white;
        max-width: 700px;">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <%= image_tag("logo-green.svg") %>
        </div><br><br>
        <div>
            <p>Welcome <%= @user.first_name %>!</p>

            <p style="line-height: 1.5">Let's confirm your email address. Click the button below to confirm your email.</p>

            <%= link_to 'CONFIRM ACCOUNT',
            confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token),
            style: "font-family: Raleway-SemiBold, sans-serif;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                display: inline-block;
                cursor: pointer;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                    padding: 13px 30px;
                    font-size: 0.8em;
                    color: #fff;
                    background-color: #00BA9B;
                    transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
                    transition-delay: 0.2s;
                    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
                    margin-top: 25px;
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                    border-radius:" %>

            <br><br>
            <p style="line-height: 1.5">Thanks,<br>website <br> <a href="www.website.com" style="color: #00BA9B; text-decoration:none">www.website.com</a></p>
            <br>

             <p style="color:grey; font-size:11px;">P.S. If you didn't sign up for website, please ignore this email - apologies for the disturbance.<p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I see that any of CSS on `CONFIRM ACCOUNT` a tag is not working at all and `<%= image_tag("logo-green.svg") %>` is not loaded at all too.

It is very strange that it works in hotmail but not in Gmail.

Would love to get any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define your image as an attachment in your mailer. E.g. I have a mailer in `app/mailers/customer_mailer.rb` that has a method `verification_confirmation`. In this method I have the following line:

`attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/logo.png"))`

Now, in the view for this email (i.e. `app/views/customer_mailer/verification_confirmation.html.erb` I can now embed the image like this:

`<%= image_tag attachments['logo.png'].url, style: "width: 15vw; min-width: 200px;" %>`

Comment: how about the CSS? CSS is not also working in gmail :/

Comment: Yeah, actually I don't know how to fix that. I have all my email styles inline in the mail views and it works fine in Gmail. I'm afraid you can not use classes with associated styles (e.g. `main wrapper clearfix`) if you want the HTML to be correctly styled in Gmail.

Comment: Hi @chndt Could you find how to fix this please ? I have the same issue.